# IllegalArgumentException: Access key cannot be null

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

Trying to connect to aws s3 bucket using AmazonS3 and AmazonS3ClientBuilder using BasicAWSCredentials, I have my access key and secret key in the **application.properties**, I followed a [**video tutorial**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbOBIexAyjA) and did exactly the same. When I run the spring boot application if throws **IllegalArgumentException:Access key cannot be null.**

S3 Configuration

```
@Configuration
public class S3Config {

    @Bean
    public AmazonS3 s3() {
        // Create credentials
        AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(Constants.ACCESS_KEY, Constants.SECRET);

        // Create Client filter pattern
        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withRegion(Constants.REGION)
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
                .build();
    }

}
```

Constants Class

```
public class Constants {

    @Value("${accessKey}")
    public static String ACCESS_KEY;

    @Value("${secret}")
    public static String SECRET;

    @Value("${region}")
    public static String REGION;

    @Value("${bucket}")
    public static String BUCKET;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using an outdated SDK version. You are using **AWS SDK for Java V1**. The recommended version is to use [AWS SDK for Java V2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html). To use credentials in AWS SDK for Java V2, you can use the default cred provider - which you can read here in the *AWS Java V2 DEV Guide*:

[Default credentials provider chain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials-chain.html)

Test your V2 code to make sure you setup the S3 V2 Java Service client by listing your S3 buckets using this code.

```
// snippet-start:[s3.java2.hello.main]
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.Bucket;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.ListBucketsResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Before running this Java V2 code example, set up your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For more information, see the following documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */
public class HelloS3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
            .region(region)
            .build();

        listBuckets(s3);
    }

    public static void listBuckets(S3Client s3) {
        try {
            ListBucketsResponse response = s3.listBuckets();
            List<Bucket> bucketList = response.buckets();
            bucketList.forEach(bucket -> {
                System.out.println("Bucket Name: " + bucket.name());
            });

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

You can find this Java V2 example and many others here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/s3

And the V2 SDK works fine in Spring Boot apps as well as shown in this doc. This doc discusses how to develop a dynamic web application that analyzes nature images located in an Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) bucket by using the AWS SDK for Java V2.

[Creating a dynamic web application that analyzes photos using the AWS SDK for Java](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases/creating_photo_analyzer_app)

Read the dev guide, try the S3 Java code examples, and even go through the example Spring Boot app to gain a much deeper understanding of how to use ***AWS SDK for Java v2*** to build apps.

Comment: Thanks smac2020, I removed the Constants variables and directly accessing them from the class where its required.